# Use Prebuilt so in Android studio

Tags: android, shared-libraries, swig

I am new to android studio.
I am trying to use so file generated from **CPP** file using swig in android studio.But am unable to do it.Thanks!!

Comment: using swig means what ?

Comment: Genrated so file and java file from c file using swig library

Comment: did you check [this](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Android.html)?

Comment: Yes,I have checked that but he refers to eclipse instead android studio.

Comment: Am able to generate so file but am unable to use in android studio